# Groupby, Unstack, and Plot from Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dask

I have a data frame that is ~87 million rows, so I am using Dask. I am trying to do something as follows:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['A','B'])['B'].count().unstack('A')
df2.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)
```

That is what I would do in Pandas, but Dask does not have 'unstack' and 'plot'. I can try using `.compute()` to get the Dask DF back to Pandas, but I run the risk of memory issues. Any ideas how (or if) I can accomplish the two lines above?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot_table`, which is available in dask. You can see the results look the same if you run the code below. If not, you can probably tweak the call to `pivot_table` to achieve the intended result.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(ascii_lowercase), 'B': [str(i) for i in range(1, 14)] * 2, 'C': np.random.normal(10, 2, 26)}) 

df1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['B'].count().unstack('A') 
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='B', columns='A', aggfunc='count')
```